# Are inflammation and anxiety connected?

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, pharmacology

I've been reading a curious paper about the use of cannabis, and one of the passages piqued my interest:

> There’s also been a lot of work done on another constituent of
>   marijuana, cannabinoid, which is not psychoactive by itself. A lot of
>   research has shown that it’s a great **anti-inflammatory**, it’s a
>   neuro-protectant, and it **may be what gives medical marijuana patients
>   relief from things like epilepsy and anxiety**

**Has there been any scientific evidence that links inflammation and anxiety?**

Source:
[Cannabis, Forgetting, and the
The Botany of Desire](https://www.erowid.org/plants/cannabis/cannabis_culture13.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

See [this](http://farncombe.mcmaster.ca/documents/ChronicGastroInflammationInducesAnxiety-LikeBehavior-Bercik.pdf) paper on link between inflammation and anxiety.

Also, quoting one of the paragraphs of this paper

> Clinical
>   studies have shown increased serum inﬂammatory markers in patients with depression as well as a correlation
>   between plasma cytokine levels and the severity of depression, and have described improvement in depression
>   after anti-inﬂammatory treatment.

Even if you do a simple google search, you will get thousands of results on this.